# How to extract the second ID from a Firebase Realtime Database path using Java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Getting data from FireBase RealTime Database

How can I get the second id from the following path: `/Requests/krZF9AMNmwZO6cxuqZFaVJA8ZNg1/x0PTLSiX61MGNfkfVVnjsn9VsZy1`? if the first id is the user who sent the request and the second one should get it and output data from it. The first and second id were chosen as an example they may differ.

[image: How it looks in RealTime Database]

Comment: Do you know the first-level ID (`krZF9...`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the first level ID (`krZF9...`), you can read all data under that node, and loop over the children with:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Requests/krZF9AMNmwZO6cxuqZFaVJA8ZNg1");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot secondSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = secondSnapshot.getKey(); // x0PTLSiX61MGNfkfVVnjsn9VsZy1
            String status = secondSnapshot.child("status").getValue(String.clasS);
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```